# How to remove a language version of a data template?

Tags: multilingual, templates, versions

I created German versions of several data templates by accident.

For regular items, there's an option to remove a version at tab "Versions" –> section "Versions":

[image]

For templates, though, the whole "Versions" section is missing.

I'd like to remove all template versions that are not English. How do I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sitecore doesn't expose the version manager [you've shown] on templates. However, you can use the DB Browser (`~/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx`) and manage items, templates, etc. that way. Simply point your browser to http://instance/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx:

[image: dbbrowser overview]

Then navigate to the template you're looking to modify and select the version you're after and select `Delete Version`:

[image: dbbrowser delete version]

Comment: Thank you, that works! Is there any possibility that the items of this template will get changed when I delete a template version? Also, should I copy standard values fields from the German version to the English version before I delete them?

Comment: For the former, like any standard values, you have the potential of changing an item that doesn't have its own data. As far as migrating data, that's up to your use case.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is using [Sitecore Powershell Extenstions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx). There is a cmdlet called [`Remove-ItemLanguage`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Remove-ItemLanguage.html), this removes the specified language version from the item.

Example that removes the German version of a template:

```ps
Get-Item master:\templates\User Defined\MyTemplate | Remove-ItemLanguage -Language de-de
```

You could create a script that would load all the items you created the language for and loop through them removing the German language pretty easily.

Comment: It doesn't remove or affect related items, right? :)

Comment: According to the docs, it just removes the language version for the specified item, will not affect anything that references that item.